# how to compare probability/ratios

Tags: probability, statistics, recreational-mathematics

For one location, I have:

Number of lollipops selling at morning time

Number of lollipops selling at afternoon time

Selling periods: Every 30 minutes is a period, which sells lollies either morning or afternoon

Q1: I would like to calculate the probability of morning and afternoon lolly sold. My formula:

Location                     Morning    Afternoon   Total

---

Number of lollies           **2        10            12**

---

Selling periods                **1         2            3**

---

Ratio                          **2         5            4**

P(Moring) = 2/4 = 0.5

P(Afternoon) = 5/4 = 1.25

If I take the ratio of: P(Afternoon)/P(Morning). Will it be called?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm not 100% sure what do you mean by your question, but here:**

As you took the ratios just compare them; $\frac{A\space (Morning \space Sells)}{D \space (Morning \space Events)}$ with $\frac{B\space (Afternoon\space Sells)}{E \space (Afternoon\space Events)}$

Lets say you have $16$ morning events and $8$ morning sells, that means that every second lollipop was sold, or $0.5$= 50%  sell rate.

Now lets say you have then $18$ afternoon events and only $6$ afternoon sells, here you get by the same logic the sell rate of $\frac{1}{3}$ or 33% sell rate.

Then you conclude that there was $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{6}$ more sells in the morning, or ~16% better sell rate.

Now you know for how much and when there are more sells.

If you want to compare on which location there were more/less sells just compare the ratios of each location.

**I believe this answers your second question;**
...And if you want to know if there were total of more morning or afternoon sells considering all locations, you can just sum up the sell ratios and calculate the average sell ratio in the mornings and average sell ratio in the afternoon and see which time of the day sells better.

---

Its still not clear to me tho what do you mean by F? Numbers of no lollipop events? ...when each event is a lollipop event? (Either a lollipop sold or not sold)

---

Comment: Thanks Matta for the help. Sorry if there is a confusion. F is an important figure. Saying that 1 day is 24hrs. At 1 location, every an hour (= 1 event) will have lollies sold in the morning, or afternoon or not at all. I calculate numbers of lolly by hours. For example, 4pm has one lolly sold, and 5pm has no lolly sold. Will it be clearer?

Comment: I am not sure if my thinking is correct. I have 2 approaches. Approach1: I calculate the ratio: A/D, B/E and C/F. I then calculate a relative risk ratio of morning lolly by taking (A/D)/(C/F), afternoon lolly by taking (B/E)/(C/F) to see whether morning or afternoon has more lolly sold out taking into account no lolly sold. But then I am stuck and don't know how to see the trend of no lolly sold. Approach2. I calculate `LocA No lolly morning afternoon Total
Number 2 4 5 11
event 10 2 10 22
ratio 0.2 2  0.50   0.50 
P(0)  0.40    
P(Mor)  4.00    
p(arvo) 1`

Comment: I'm confused with the data at LocA in your Approach2: 4 morning lollies, but 2 morning events if I'm reading right?, So 2 lollies sold per event, but you said each event sells or not sells one lolly?(Or you meant 2,10,10?) Could you update your question with the example of data and your progress so far and the place where you get stuck so its more clear of what the actual problem is?

Comment: Hi Matta, I just edit my question. What would u think my calculation? Thanks